# How to convert ’ into '

Tags: vb.net, rss, quote, apostrophe

I would like to convert ’ (apostrophe) into ' (single quotes). I am reading data from rss and would to save that into DB. While saving the apostrophe it's saving as ? (question mark). Is tehre any way to change to to single quotes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why dont you show your `into` code ...

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the **.replace** method

i.e. `Yourstringname.ToString.Replace("'","''")`

Comment: `Replace` has to work (both characters are different for VB.NET) but your code is not written properly; change it to: `Yourstringname.Replace("’","'")`. See? I cannot (shouldn't) modify others' code :)